# After Calling API does not wait for Response

Tags: iphone, ios

Problem is that i am call megnto api but when api return the object before that all other statements are got executed .

```
NSMutableArray *list=[Magento.service startSession];

    NSLog(@"Record is:%@",list);
```

startSession method that i have modified is:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)startSession
{
 NSString *_sessionID;
    NSNumber *nsPage =[NSNumber  numberWithInt:1];
    NSNumber *nsData =[NSNumber  numberWithInt:10];
    NSMutableArray *listOfName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nsPage,nsData,nil ];
    @synchronized(self) {
  _sessionID = sessionID;
 }
 if (_sessionID != FAILED_SESSION)
  dispatch_group_enter(session_group);
 [client postPath:@"login" parameters:@{@"username": MAGENTO_USERNAME, @"apiKey": MAGENTO_API_KEY}  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  sessionID = responseObject;



  dispatch_group_leave(session_group);

        [client postPath:@"call" parameters:@{@"sessionId":sessionID, @"resourcePath":@"callforprice_collection.getCallForPriceCollection",
         @"args":args
         } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationData, id responseData) {

             NSLog(@"Response :  %@",responseData);
             [listOfName addObject:[responseData valueForKey:@"name"]];

         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationData, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Response is not get");
             sessionID = FAILED_SESSION;
         }];


        NSLog(@"got session %@", sessionID);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  sessionID = FAILED_SESSION;
 }];
    return  listOfName;

}
```

**o/p is**

```
2013-05-03 06:27:16.272 CallForPrice[3120:c07] Record is: ()
2013-05-03 06:27:19.836 CallForPrice[3120:c07] got session 88ef34087a12809334ae3a0c839f85b6
** response that i have printed in method**
2013-05-03 06:27:22.048 CallForPrice[3120:c07] Response :  (
        {
        "callforprice_id" = 13;
        country = Austria;
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 12:03:05";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = hfhftrfygjh;
        name = "Richard Conover";
        "phone_no" = 8977896;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "callforprice_id" = 12;
        country = "Antigua and Barbuda";
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 12:01:24";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = sdfsdfsdfwe;
        name = "Richard Conover";
        "phone_no" = 5645;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    },
        {
        "callforprice_id" = 11;
        country = Angola;
        "created_time" = "2013-05-03 11:58:51";
        emailid = "indies.tester@gmail.com";
        message = 6tyrtyryrty;
        name = "Kaitlyn Matheson";
        "phone_no" = 564564;
        "product_name" = Ottoman;
        "product_options" = "";
        "update_time" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    },
```

startSession is displaying the record actually what happen is  NSLOG is printed before call do response . How to solve this problem.s

Comment: Because it's renewSession run on different thread

Comment: Why is that one line commented out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add this line after all imports in Magento.h

```
typedef void(^completion)(NSArray *list);
```

2) change the method signature, both in .h and .m

```
- (void)startSession:(completion) completion
```

3) in Magento.m, modify your method with this

```
- (void)startSession:(completion) completion
{

        NSString *_sessionID;
        NSNumber *nsPage =[NSNumber  numberWithInt:1];
        NSNumber *nsData =[NSNumber  numberWithInt:10];
        NSMutableArray *listOfName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nsPage,nsData,nil ];
        @synchronized(self) {
            _sessionID = sessionID;
        }
        if (_sessionID != FAILED_SESSION)
            dispatch_group_enter(session_group);
        [client postPath:@"login" parameters:@{@"username": MAGENTO_USERNAME, @"apiKey": MAGENTO_API_KEY}  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            sessionID = responseObject;



            dispatch_group_leave(session_group);

            [client postPath:@"call" parameters:@{@"sessionId":sessionID, @"resourcePath":@"callforprice_collection.getCallForPriceCollection",
             @"args":args
             } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationData, id responseData) {

                 NSLog(@"Response :  %@",responseData);
                 [listOfName addObject:[responseData valueForKey:@"name"]];

                 completion(listOfName);

             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationData, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Response is not get");
                 sessionID = FAILED_SESSION;
                 completion(nil);
             }];


            NSLog(@"got session %@", sessionID);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            sessionID = FAILED_SESSION;
            completion(nil);
        }];

}
```

4)in your viewController.h , declare a global variable to hold returned name,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *nameList;

// and in viewDidLoad method,
self.nameList = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

5) put this code fragment, in viewDidLoad or

```
[Magento.service startSession:^(NSArray *list) {
    if(list){
        self.nameList = list;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }else self.nameList = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}];
```

6) use `self.nameList` array to load the table

Comment: i have one question how can i pass parameter to startSession method

Comment: which type of parameter my friend ? If it's a String you can use this kind of a method, - (void)startSession:(completion) completion withString:(NSString *) inputString

Comment: thank you dear !!! i though after using completion block we can not pass any another parameter so Silly i am . Thank you for replay fast. and thank you i have near about to complete my application .

Comment: when i call this method second time it is giving me error ,frnd please me, something like NSPlaceHolderDictionary attempte insert nil object into object[0]

Answer (score 1):

Alloc the NSMutableArray first and make sure [Magento.service renewSession] actually returns an array.

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
list=[Magento.service renewSession];
//[Magento.service getCallForPriceData];
NSLog(@"Record is:%@",list);
```

Comment: Problem is not that but , I am calling different method rather than i have modified but still it is given reponse nil and than result

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the renewSession method and make sure it's actually creating the array first. You say you modified the method to return an array so that is where the problem lyes more than likely.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know Magneto API, but i met with this behavior before. This is an asyncronous method. In startSession it will return with the empty list, and make the async call (on different thread). And in the response you do nothing with results. (Block stores the local references, thats why you could add something to it). Try to define a

```
startSessionWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSArray* list))completionBlock;
```

function and change response handler to:

```
NSLog(@"Response :  %@",responseData);
[listOfName addObject:[responseData valueForKey:@"name"]];
completionBlock(listOfName);
```

and call

```
[Magento.service startSessionWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray* list){
   NSLog(@"Record is:%@",list);
}];
```

This will only put the first object in the list and return with it (just to show it actually returns with something). You need to define some logic to count the async downloaded items too.